# Python, sort a list by another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list `a`:

```
a = ['c','d','b','a','e']
```

and a list `b`:

```
b = ['a001','b002','c003','d004','e005']
```

and how could I get my list `c` as following:

```
c = ['c003','d004','b002','a001','e005']
```

Basically sort `b` using part of each element, by the order defined in `a`.

Many Thanks.

Comment: This is **subtly different from** the question Martijn originally used as a duplicate - I am currently on the hunt for the best possible canonical, and have swapped in the best result I have found so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try passing a `lambda` function to the `key` parameter of the `sorted()` built-in function:

```
a = ['c', 'd', 'B', 'a', 'e']
b = ['a001', 'B002', 'c003', 'd004', 'e005']
c = sorted(b, key = lambda x: a.index(x[0])) # ['c003', 'd004', 'b002', 'a001', 'e005']
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. `index` will perform an _O(N)_ search  on `a` resulting in an `O(N² log N)` sort.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a very big list, the solutions using `.index` will not be very efficient as the first list will be `index`'d for each entry in the second list. This will take O(n^2) time.

Instead, you can construct a sort mapping:

```
order = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(a)}
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x: order[x[0]])
```

Comment: question: how many times is `key` called during a sort? `n`? is there a cache made of key results?

Comment: @njzk2: IIRC `key` is computed once for each element and stored. This is in contrast to the `cmp` argument, which is evaluated once per comparison.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using the `key` named argument of `sorted()`:

```
c = sorted(b, key = lambda e: a.index(e[0]))
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. `index` will perform an _O(N)_ search  on `a` resulting in an `O(N² log N)` sort.

Comment: Sorts are normally said to be `O(N log N)`, where `N` is the number of elements in the list.  That's not necessarily the same number as the number of elements in `a`.  If `a` is small, then this could be faster than setting up a `dict`.  As usual, test the performance using data from your use case.