# Sorting and filtering one list based on another

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort one list based on another list.

Example: below I would like to sort `list_sec` based on `key` in this list and the order would be from `list_main`.

```
list_main = [3, 33, 2]

list_sec = [{'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'}, {'key': 332, 'rocket': 'mark23'}, {'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'} ]
```

Output would be as below. (explanation: first element in `list_main` is 3, so `key` : 3 should come to index = 0, second value is 33 but this key is missing in `list_sec` so will discard this. third key is 2, so this will come next.

```
output = [{'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'}, {'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'}]
```

I have read couple of answers on similar lines:
[Python, sort a list by another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069055/python-sort-a-list-by-another-list) ,
[Python 3.x -- sort one list based on another list and then return both lists sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024568/python-3-x-sort-one-list-based-on-another-list-and-then-return-both-lists-sor)

But stuck without attempt. Any way this can be done.

Comment: You want not just sorting but filtering too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sorted(list(filter(lambda data: data["key"] in list_main, list_sec)),
       key=lambda data: list_main.index(data["key"]))
```

output:

```
[{'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'}, {'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform your list of dicts into a dict, then you'll be able to retrieve items by value of `key`.

```
In [2]: rocket_dict = {item['key']: item for item in list_sec}

In [3]: rocket_dict
Out[3]: 
{2: {'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'},
 332: {'key': 332, 'rocket': 'mark23'},
 3: {'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'}}
```

If you need a list in that particular order, you can do:

```
In [4]: output = []

In [5]: for key in list_main:
   ...:     if key in rocket_dict:
   ...:         output.append(rocket_dict[key])
   ...: 

In [6]: output
Out[6]: [{'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'}, {'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method it will work in your case

```
list_main = [3, 33, 2]

list_sec = [{'key': 2, 'rocket': 'mark11'}, {'key': 332, 'rocket': 'mark23'}, {'key': 3, 'rocket': 'mark1'} ]

sorted_list = [] # The final sorted list
for key in list_main:  # iterate on each key
    for item in list_sec:
        if item['key'] == key: # find the item based on your key
            sorted_list.append(item) # append in sequence
print(sorted_list) # your sorted list
```

Comment: Iterating over the second list for every item in the first one is not very effective, though.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially @LevLevitsky's answer, but with list comprehension

```py
wrap_dict = {item['key']: item for item in list_sec}
output = [wrap_dict[key] for key in list_main if key in wrap_dict]
```

Or we can use the coolest [walrus operator introduced in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

```
output = [rkt_dict for key in list_main if (rkt_dict := wrap_dict.get(key))]
```